# How to configure the vertx instance itself only once and use it in application code and tests?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, configuration, vert.x

I am currently migrating one of our clojure services to vert.x, using kotlin as main language. Most things work like a charm, but there is one issue I am struggling with for quite some time now.

All of our services use [micrometer.io](https://micrometer.io/) and [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) to collect metrics. According to the [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-micrometer-metrics/java/#_prometheus), integrating micrometer is straight-forward:

```
val vertx = Vertx.vertx(
    VertxOptions().setMetricsOptions(
        MicrometerMetricsOptions()
            .setPrometheusOptions(VertxPrometheusOptions().setEnabled(true))
            .setEnabled(true)
    )
)
```

In general, this approach works nicely - metrics are gathered and exposed by adding a separate route:

```
router.get("/metrics").handler(PrometheusScrapingHandler.create())
```

The problem I am struggling with is, that there is no way I am aware of to define these vert.x-related settings (`VertxOptions`) only once and publish them globally - basically whenever a new `Vertx` instance is created.

This is an issue, because currently I have to define these settings on three different places:

1.) **Server.kt**

Allows to start the service with my IDE

2.) **ServerLauncher**

The purpose of this class is to start the server from the commandline with gradle.

3.) **Integration tests**

Vert.x provides a nifty junit5 extension (`VertxExtension`) which automatically injects the `Vertx` and `VertxTestContext` instances in your [test methods](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-junit5/java/#_test_methods). The downside is that there is no way to configure the injected `Vertx` instance as it always injects it with [default settings](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-junit5/blob/3.6.2/src/main/java/io/vertx/junit5/VertxExtension.java#L108).

Thus you have to wire everything on your own in your test method:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Call prometheus endpoint and verify core metrics are present")
fun callPrometheusEndpoint(testCtx: VertxTestContext) {
    val vertx = Vertx.vertx(
        VertxOptions().setMetricsOptions(
            MicrometerMetricsOptions()
                .setPrometheusOptions(VertxPrometheusOptions().setEnabled(true))
                .setEnabled(true)
        )
    )
    vertx.deployVerticle(
        MyVerticle(),
        testCtx.completing()
    )
    WebClient.create(vertx)
        .get(8080, "localhost", "/internal/prometheus")
        .`as`(BodyCodec.string())
        .send(testCtx.succeeding { resp ->
            testCtx.verify {
                // assertions to follow...
                testCtx.completeNow()
            }
        })
}
```

I am wondering, if there is any way to define the `VertxOptions` only once and thus override/complement the default settings used, whenever a `Vertx` instance is created?

**Update 1**

I decided to extract a separate `Application` class in order to configure the `Vertx` instance and get rid of `Server.kt` and `ServerLauncher.kt`.

```
class Application(
    private val profileSetting: String? = System.getenv("ACTIVE_PROFILES"),
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application::class.java)!!
) {

    fun bootstrap() {
        val profiles = activeProfiles()

        val vertx = bootstrapVertx(profiles)
        val configRetriever = bootstrapConfigRetriever(vertx, profiles)

        val myVerticle = MyVerticle(configRetriever)

        vertx.deployVerticle(myVerticle) { startup ->
            if (startup.succeeded()) {
                logger.info("Application startup finished")
            } else {
                logger.error("Application startup failed", startup.cause())
                vertx.close()
            }
        }
    }

    internal fun activeProfiles(): List<String> {
        logger.info("Configured profiles: {}", profileSetting)
        return profileSetting
            ?.let { it.split(',').map { p -> p.trim() }.filter { p -> p.isNotBlank() } }
            ?: emptyList()
    }

    internal fun bootstrapVertx(profiles: List<String>): Vertx {
        registerModules()
        val vertxOptions = VertxOptionsFactory(profiles).create()
        return Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions)
    }

    internal fun bootstrapConfigRetriever(vertx: Vertx, profiles: List<String>): ConfigRetriever {
        return ConfigRetrieverFactory(profiles).create(vertx)
    }

    private fun registerModules() {
        Json.mapper.apply { registerKotlinModule() }
        Json.prettyMapper.apply { registerKotlinModule() }
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) = Application().bootstrap()
    }
}
```

I found no way to pass the configured `Vertx` instance to the `VertxExtention` though.

**Update 2**

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-junit5/pull/56) that addresses the issue of pre-configuring vertx instances in tests.

Answer (score 2):

Since Vert.x 3.6.0, you can put [Vert.x options in a file](https://vertx.io/blog/eclipse-vert-x-3-6-0-released/#externalized-configuration-of-vert-x-options) and load them with `-options`. That works if you are using the CLI or a `Launcher` class.

When you have to start Vert.x in embedded mode (eg tests), you can read the file content, and create the `VertxOptions` instance from a `JsonObject`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the possibility to provide a separate configuration file. My main problem with the test setup is that I cannot really configure the vertx instance provided by the VertxExtension during test execution, thus I have to initialise the vertx instance manually inside every test method and take care of setup/teardown, awaitingResponse and the like on myself which defeats the purpose of the extension in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share some more info to @tsegismont answer.

To use prometheus metrics you can define `options.json` as following (after adding necessary includes to your pom or build.gradle):

```json
{ "metricsOptions": {
  "enabled": true,
  "prometheusOptions" : {
    "enabled": true, 
    "embeddedServerOptions": {"port": 8080},
    "startEmbeddedServer": true 
} } }
```

it will expose metrices on `host:8080/metrics`

To put more options into `options.json` - I just scanned source code of

```
BareCommand.getMetricsOptions
MicrometerMetricsOptionsConverter.fromJson
```

There are easy to read json parsing functions.

1. To add options to your jar:
   `java -jar your-vertx-app.jar -options options.json`
2. To use it from IDE, you may use `Launcher.executeCommand`:

java:

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Launcher.executeCommand("run", args);
}
```

kotlin:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Launcher.executeCommand("run", "com.your.LauncherVerticle", *args)
}
```

Afther that you can pass `-options options.json` parameters in case of kotlin or `com.your.LauncherVerticle -options options.json` in case of java to program arguments of your run configuration. `Launcher.executeCommand` will use this file.

3. For unit tests [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-junit5/java/#_test_methods) states:
   "Note
   The Vertx instance is not clustered and has the default configuration. If you need something else then just don’t use injection on that parameter and prepare a Vertx object by yourself."